# change in $? after the call to close in perl

Tags: perl, pipe

Following is the code

```
use strict;  
use warnings;

my $cmd = "ls";  
my $pid = open(INPUT,"$cmd 2>&1 |");  
print "PID = [$pid] [$?]\n";  
if (!defined($pid)) {  
    print "PID not defined\n";  
} else {  
    print "BEFORE CLOSING exit code is [$?]\n";  
}  
close INPUT;  
print "AFTER CLOSING [$?]\n";
```

The output is as follows :

```
PID = [32300] [0]  
BEFORE CLOSING exit code is [0]  
AFTER CLOSING [13]
```

Why the value of $? changes after the call to close()?

Comment: 13 is SIGPIPE; it just indicates that you closed a pipe that `ls` was still trying to write to.

Answer (score 2):

According the documentation of [perl close](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html):

...
Closing a pipe also waits for the process executing on the pipe to exit--in case you wish to look at the output of the pipe afterwards--and implicitly puts the exit status value of that command into `$?` and `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}`.
...

So in you example, `$?` contains the exit status of the command ls

Comment: Note: It's actually `sh` (not `ls`) being executed, so it's actually `sh`'s exit status in `$?`. That said, `sh`'s exit status will be `ls`'s most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

[`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) says that `$?` is:

> The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (`` ) command, successful call to wait() or waitpid(), or from the system() operator.

So clearly it has to reflect the status of your pipe close. Before any of these operations its contents are meaningless.

Comment: As documented in both [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [`close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html)